# Why elasticsearch is not strongly typed?

Tags: elasticsearch

[image]Mapping.json :

```
{ "XYZ": { "properties" :{
     "p": { "type": "string"  }
     "q": { "type": "boolean" }
     "r": { "type":"nested", "properties": { "s": { "type": "integer"}, "t": { "type": "string" } } }

}
}
```

Pushing http://localhost:9200/myindex/XYZ/1/_create

[image]
data.json

```
{
      "p":"p1","q":"true", "r": [ { "t":"sIntegerMissingBefore"}]
}
```

[image]
Even some of the fields are missing, hierarchical change on the data side, elastic-search accepts loads the data without throwing data is of wrong type

When we perform search nested-queries, it shows an empty hits object, even after having the nested-data, Why elasticsearch is not so typed ?

Comment: So which fields do you expect to violate your type constraints?

Comment: As data for "s": { "type": "integer"} is missing in the above example, as it is not mandating for the missing fields, and in my real example we are missing some hierarchical object but accepts it and stores the data on cluster